# C++11 template specialization with void type and argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In a **C++11** program, I define these templates:

```
namespace outcome {

template <class T>
class c_out {
    public:
        bool success = false;
        std::string error = "";
        T result;
};

template <class T>
c_out<T> failed(T res, const std::string& error_msg = "") {
    c_out<T> outcome;
    outcome.success = false;
    outcome.error = error_msg;
    return outcome;
};

template <class T>
c_out<T> succeeded(T res) {
    c_out<T> outcome;
    outcome.success = true;
    outcome.result = res;
    return outcome;
};

};
```

I want to specialize them when *class T* is *void*. It works out easily for *c_out*:

```
template <>
class c_out<void> {
    public:
        bool success = false;
        std::string error = "";
};
```

However, I keep getting errors for the other two functions. How can I specialize them?

```
c_out<void> failed(const std::string& error_msg = "") {
    c_out<void> outcome;
    outcome.success = false;
    outcome.error = error_msg;
    return outcome;
};

c_out<void> succeeded(void) {
    c_out<void> outcome;
    outcome.success = true;
    return outcome;
};
```

**Errors**: When I call

```
outcome::succeeded();
```

in *YYY.cpp*, I get errors linking the library:

```
lib/libXXX.a(YYY.cpp.o): In function `outcome::failed(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
YYY.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `outcome::failed(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/ZZZ.dir/main/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
lib/libXXX.a(YYY.cpp.o): In function `outcome::succeeded()':
YYY.cpp:(.text+0x50): multiple definition of `outcome::succeeded()'
CMakeFiles/ZZZ.dir/main/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x50): first defined here
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Please paste them into the question verbatim.

Comment: Your code [compiles without error](https://godbolt.org/z/2H_CNG). Perhaps you're getting errors elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't specializations. Those are overloads. And they are regular functions, which is important, because function template specializations have a few properties by default that regular functions don't have.

For instance, templates can appear in a header, and so be defined in multiple translation units without a problem. Templates are *implicitly inline*. Regular functions need to be made explicitly inline.

Your error indicates you defined those overloads in a header file. Including it into multiple translation units caused multiple definitions to appear, and the functions are not inline, so that's an ill-formed program right there.

The solution is to either move those overloads to a dedicated TU, and expose only their declarations. Or you can mark them inline in the header:

```
inline c_out<void> failed(const std::string& error_msg = "") {
    c_out<void> outcome;
    outcome.success = false;
    outcome.error = error_msg;
    return outcome;
};

inline c_out<void> succeeded(void) {
    c_out<void> outcome;
    outcome.success = true;
    return outcome;
};
```

This will spit out an inline definition in every TU. So long as all the definitions are exactly the same (which is true for a function in a header), the program will be well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

1.Please make sure that you don`t use different files when compiling. For example if you have your template class into a header file and the main into a different .cpp file that may cause the program  to crash because it it searching for a template in the .cpp file which is the case given above is not existent. That may be the cause of the problem.

2. Some IDEs don`t have that problem, so you might like to try another IDE and check if the same error appears.